# I'm having trouble with my stack pop() method

Tags: java, stack

I'm having a lot of issues with my this code. I'm trying to make a program for homework that scans a text file and makes sure all brackets and parentheses (deliminator) match as pairs. I made a DelimPos class and built a constructor. This became my stack "s". Every time I encounter an opening delim in the file I push it onto the stack. When I encounter a closing delim I want to compare it to the top of the stack and pop the stack if the pair matches. When I pop the stack it returns a DelimPos type, but doesn't remove it from the stack.

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and provide any other criticisms you have. Just want to get a better.

```
    public class BalancedApp {

private static class DelimPos {

    private static int linecnt;
    private static char ch;

    public DelimPos(int lineCount, char character) { //constructor
        linecnt = lineCount;
        ch = character;
    }

    public static boolean match(char closeDelim) {
        if (getCharacter() == '(' && closeDelim == ')') return true;
        if (getCharacter() == '[' && closeDelim == ']') return true;
        if (getCharacter() == '{' && closeDelim == '}') return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static char getCharacter() {
        return ch;
    }

    public static int getLineCount() {
        return linecnt;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //initialize stack
    Stack<DelimPos> s = new Stack<DelimPos>();

    int lineCount = 1;

    //get input for file
    System.out.printf("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    try{
        //check for file,open, and scan it
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        inFile.useDelimiter("");

        String text;
        System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");

        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            text = inFile.next();
            char character = text.charAt(0);

        //-------NEW LINE-------
            if(character == '\n') {
                //System.out.print(character);
                lineCount++;
                System.out.print("\n"+lineCount + ". ");
            }

        //-------CHECK FOR OPEN DELIM AND ADD TO STACK IF TRUE-------
            else if(character == '(' || character == '{' || character == '[') {
                System.out.print(character);
                s.push(new DelimPos(lineCount, character));
            }

        //-------CHECK FOR CLOSING DELIM, PRINT APPROPROATE ERROR, AND POP STACK
            else if(character == ')' || character == '}' || character == ']') {
                System.out.print(character);

                //---WHEN THERE IS AN EXTRA CLOSING DELIM---
                if (s.empty() == true) {
                    System.out.printf("\nError: Line %d. Closing character '%c', with no matching character.", lineCount, character);
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                boolean answer = DelimPos.match(character);

                //---WHEN CLOSING DELIM DOES NOT BALANCE WITH OPENING DELIM---
                if(answer == false) {
                    System.out.printf("\nError: Line %d. Symbol '%c' is the wrong closing symbol for char = '%c', line %d.", lineCount, character, DelimPos.getCharacter(), DelimPos.getLineCount());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                else {
                    s.pop();  //<<<<<<<<<-----Where I'm having an issue
                    }
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nInput is balanced.");

        inFile.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.printf("Unable to open file %s\n", fileName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

    import java.util.Stack;
```

----Editted code below, changed static objects into instance objects. @JeffWard explains below.----

```
public class BalancedApp {

private static class DelimPos {

    private int linecnt;
    private char ch;

    public DelimPos(int lineCount, char character) { //constructor
        linecnt = lineCount;
        ch = character;
    }

    public boolean match(char closeDelim) {
        if (this.getCharacter() == '(' && closeDelim == ')') return true;
        if (this.getCharacter() == '[' && closeDelim == ']') return true;
        if (this.getCharacter() == '{' && closeDelim == '}') return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public char getCharacter() {
        return ch;
    }

    public int getLineCount() {
        return linecnt;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int lineCount = 1;

    //get input for file
    System.out.printf("Enter file name: ");
    String fileName = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    try{
        //initialize stack
        Stack<DelimPos> s = new Stack<DelimPos>();

        //check for file,open, and scan it
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        inFile.useDelimiter("");

        String text;
        System.out.print(lineCount + ". ");

        while(inFile.hasNext()){
            text = inFile.next();
            char character = text.charAt(0);

        //-------NEW LINE-------
            if(character == '\n') {
                lineCount++;
                System.out.print("\n"+lineCount + ". ");
            }

        //-------CHECK FOR OPEN DELIM AND ADD TO STACK IF TRUE-------
            else if(character == '(' || character == '{' || character == '[') {
                System.out.print(character);
                s.push(new DelimPos(lineCount, character));
            }

        //-------CHECK FOR CLOSING DELIM, PRINT APPROPROATE ERROR, AND POP STACK
            else if(character == ')' || character == '}' || character == ']') {
                System.out.print(character);

                //---WHEN THERE IS AN EXTRA CLOSING DELIM---
                if (s.empty() == true) {
                    System.out.printf("\nError: Line %d. Closing character '%c', with no matching character.", lineCount, character);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            else {
                    DelimPos data = s.pop();
                    boolean answer = data.match(character);

                    //---WHEN CLOSING DELIM DOES NOT BALANCE WITH OPENING DELIM---
                    if(answer == false) {
                        System.out.printf("\nError: Line %d. Symbol '%c' is the wrong closing symbol for char = '%c', line %d.", lineCount, character, data.getCharacter(), data.getLineCount());
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(character);
            }
        }
       if (s.empty() != true) {
           DelimPos data = s.pop();
            System.out.printf("\nError: At end of file, no closing symbol found for char = '%c', line %d.", data.getCharacter(), data.getLineCount());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("\nInput is balanced.");
            inFile.close();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.printf("Unable to open file %s\n", fileName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a **specific** error or question? Like specific examples of what behavior you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: @user3580294 Yes, my pop method isn't doing anything besides returning the top of the stack. It is supposed to return and remove the top. I can't figure out why it's not removing.

Comment: Are you sure that `s.pop()` is actually reached at any point? Also, a good way of checking that `pop()` is working is using asserts -- check size before/after and see if they are different. Because you're using Java's `Stack` I'd suspect that it works right, so the problem is likely somewhere else...

Comment: nvm, looks like I'm just bad at debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that your `DelimPos` class is static including the member variables. Every delimiter that is encountered changes the value of `ch` in all items of the stack.

Considering the following input `{{()}}`

When the first `(` is encountered the first two `{` would be changed. Add a toString() to your `DelimPos` like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Delim: " + ch;
}
```

If you run your program in a debugger and inspect you stack upon hitting the `(` character you will see that your stack contains `[Delim: (, Delim: (, Delim: (]`

Comment: Wouldn't just making the instance variables non-static be sufficient?

Comment: @user3580294 Probably but I believe the random scattering of static was because he was having difficulty creating the private class within the static main method. My suggestion was to extract it instead.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps. Maybe include a section on how `static` affects things?

Comment: @JeffWard Thank you very much. I literally just came here to say I finally fixed the problem by making instance objects instead of static. Fixed the whole thing. I vaguely understood why it worked, but your explanation helped. Edited code above.

Comment: @clenard Super! Glad I could help.